# Creating a jquery plugin with persistent data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question ... In JQUERY can define a plugin with persistent data?
For example:

```
$.myPlugin({
   name  : "Stefan",
   lastname : "Luv",
});    
$.MyPlugin({name:"Another"});

console.log($.myPlugin.getName());//prints "Another";
console.log($.myPlugin.getLastname());//prints "Luv" preserve first data;
```

Thanks

Comment: Yes, but you don't need to use jQuery.  Just use plain old javascript classes.
`function Person(firstName, lastName) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.lastName = lastName;
}

Comment: Here is a better example. If you need to use jQuery, you can, but this seems simple: http://jsfiddle.net/richbuff/p37xE/